# Create multiple Methods automatically

Tags: julia

I can define a `function` that handles `Integer`s:

```
function twice(a::Int64) a + a end
```

This function cannot handle `Float`s. If I want that, I need to define another method:

```
function twice(a::Float64) a + a end
```

But wait, this looks exactly the same, apart from the type definition. So, when I dream at night, there is a possibility to create such method definitions (everything identical apart from the type/combination of types) with a... macro maybe? Something like

```
@create_all_methods ("twice(a::$type ) a + a end", ["Int64", "Float64"])
```

1. Is this possible and if so, how?
2. Does the question maybe make no sense at all, because there is no situation where `function twice(a) a + a end` wouldn't achieve the exact same thing anyway?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Annotating arguments with their types does *not* improve performance or correctness. It only prevents a method from being called for arguments that do no match the type-asserts. The main point of annotating arguments is to control method dispatch.

Comment: Good comment - thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that. The easiest would be to just omit the type of `a`T then you methodn would look like:

```
function twice(a) a + a end
```

This is equivalent to

```
function twice(a::Any) a + a end
```

But maybe you don't want to define this for all types, or you already have another definition for `twice(a::Any)`, so you could restrict your definition to the common supertype of `Int64` and `Float64`. This common supertype can be found with `typejoin(Float64, Int64)` and yields the result `Real`, so your definition would now be

```
function twice(a::Real) a + a end
```

This also creates a method for other subtypes of `Real` such as`a::Int32`, so if you really want the method only for `Int64` and `Float64` you can create a union type. Then the method would look like

```
    function twice(a::Union{Int64, Float64}) a + a end
```

Finally, it is indeed possible to achieve what you wanted to achieve with your macro. It does not make sense in this case, but either the function `eval` or the macro `@eval` is often used in more complicated cases. Your code could then look like

```
for T in (Int64, Float64)
    @eval function twice(a::$T) a + a end
end
```

If you you just started learning Julia, I would not advice to use `eval`, as there are some dangers/anti-patterns associated with the usage of `eval`.

Answer (score 6):

A straightforward way of creating methods for two or more input types is to use `Union`:

```
twice(a::Union{T1, T2, T3}) = a + a
```

where `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, ect. are concrete types, such as `Int` or `Float64`.

More commonly, you would define it for some abstract supertype instead, for example

```
twice(a::Number) = a + a
```

But most of the time, you should just start by defining a generic function

```
twice(a) = a + a
```

and then add types when you find that it becomes necessary. Most of the time it isn't.